# RemoteControlClient and PLAYSTATE_PAUSED

Tags: android, playback

I am trying to use the remote control client in Android and I see the following behavior.

During media playback, if i am playing and call `RemoteControlClient.setPlaybackState(PLAYSTATE_PLAYING)` and then I turn the screen off and turn it back on, i get the play controls as expected.

However, if during media playback, I pause, and therefore call `RemoteControlClient.setPlaybackState(PLAYSTATE_PAUSED)` and then I turn the screen off and turn it back on, I don't see the remote controls at all!

Is this expected?  If I simply don't make the `PLAYSTATE_PAUSED` call when I pause the media player, then I turn the screen off and turn it back on, I get the wrong controls - I see a pause button (instead of a play button).

Interestingly, if I pause from the media controls on the lock screen, the lock screen widget stays up and everything works as expected.

Thoughts here?  Is this by design or a bug?

Answer (score 4):

When you pause audio are you releasing audio focus?  When you lose audio focus the controls will disappear.

Comment: I don't release audio focus, I even check I have audio focus, but I'm suffering the same problem as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a NullPointerException, do you reference RemoteControlClient in any functions that are called when you pause?

Answer (score -1):

Initially the RemoteClient doesn't display any controls when you set `PLAYSTATE_PAUSED`. This is apparently desired behavior. Instead, if you set `PLAYSTATE_PLAYING` and later switch to `PLAYSTATE_PAUSED`, it works.

Comment: as he said : 
During media playback, if i am playing and call RemoteControlClient.setPlaybackState(PLAYSTATE_PLAYING) and then I turn the screen off and turn it back on, i get the play controls as expected.